# To dream, or not to dream (a haiku)

Tags: riddle, wordplay, poetry, haiku

> *A dream, not a dream.
>
>   Tailless, tail-less. Puzzled? Makes
>
>   Quite the parable.*

---

**What am I referring to?**

---

**Hint #1:**

> There are a few cryptic-clue style indicators that I'm sure many of you have latched onto. The question is, what set of letters are they indicating? Pretty much the entire puzzle goes in order, so if you find yourself jumping around to try to solve it, you've strayed from the path.

**Hint #2:**

> The answer you seek is a single, eight-letter word.

**Hint #3:**

> *Synonymize twice.
>
>  Cryptic clue, cryptic clue. Then,
>
>  It's a synonym.*

Comment: hm, "tailless" seems suspiciously like a double curtailment indicator...

Comment: Guys, I blew it - I forgot the wordplay tag. It's been added. D:

Comment: Arrrgh @BaileyM would you stop preempting all of my puzzle types!!! First crossword, then murder mystery, now haiku! It's bad enough that all of your puzzles are so good

Comment: Is any of the capitalization important?

Comment: @MiloPrice the capitalization isn't important at all, no.

Comment: I must say, the difference between "tailless" and "tail-less" eludes me.

Comment: I think tailless is referring to removing the final letter(s) of a word whereas tail-less means removing the letters t,a,i,l from a word.

Comment: @alexmc that's surprisingly accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @Hackiisan is right but for the wrong reason.

> Allegory

A dream

> A goal

Not a dream, tailless, tail-less

> Not a dream = reality.  Remove "tai" (a tailless tail) from reality leaves "rely" (So "Not a dream, tailless, tail-less" means "remove tai from reality")

puzzled?

> anagram of "goal rely" gives you allegory

makes quite a parable

> allegory

Comment: You and @Hackiisan are right, but you need to combine your answers - specifically, your dream and his 'not a dream'.

Comment: Okay, I changed my explanation.  Think this makes more sense

Comment: *whew* I can breathe easier now. You got it!

Answer (score 6):

Is it a

> tale?

**Explanation**

*A dream, not a dream*

> Fables is dreamy and fictional, but not a literal dream.

*Tailless, tailless. Puzzled?*

> "tailless" - "less"(the "tail" end of the word) = "tail" (rhymes with "tale")
>  "Puzzled" = search for homophone of "tail" -> "tale"

*Makes quite the parable*

> "Tale" is a synonym of "parable"

Comment: You're on the right track, especially with how you've approached the second and third lines. The first line can actually be interpreted a bit more literally than that.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not fully convinced (which probably means it's incorrect as your puzzles go)

But could it be:

> Les Miserables?

A dream, not a dream.

> A reference to the song "I dreamed a dream" - and perhaps how the situation in Paris itself is not a "dream"

Tailless, tailless

> Taking the last letter from tailless cryptic style we get - Tailles which are "(in France) taxes levied on the common people by the king or an overlord" which fits with the June Rebellion in Paris that Les Mis is based on.

Puzzled? Makes
Quite the parable.

> I was hoping Les Mis would anagram to something to nicely fit in here, but alas..

Comment: Looking for anagrams is a good way to start when I'm the puzzler in question. :) Something's tailless, that's for sure - but it's not tailless. The added hyphen should help sort that out.

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking out loud in case somebody can use this

A dream, not a dream

> Daydream, an idea, a thought

Tailless, tail-less

> Tailless - tail = less, otherwise tailless - the literal tail of the word (less) = tail

Puzzled? Makes quite the parable

> My guess is that the combination of two words deduced from the first two clues forms the name of a well known parable

Comment: Deducing words is a good idea, and 'parable' being related to the final answer is also a good idea. My girlfriend made the same mistake when I walked her through this one - 'daydream', while it sounds like the opposite of a dream, is actually very similar. I would classify ideas and thoughts similarly.

Comment: How about nightmare?

Comment: I would continue to describe a nightmare as similar to a dream.

Answer (score 0):

could it be,

> Story, seems too easy for one of your puzzles

A dream, not a dream.

> A story is can be like a dream if it is fictional

Tailless, tailless. Puzzled? Makes

> Tailless, tailless sounds like tell us, tell us(At least in the south it does). puzzled? tell us what? a story. Make up a story

Quite the parable.

> parables are moral stories

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.

**Idea #1**

It's the

> Martin Luther King "[I Have A Dream](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/world/americas/3170387.stm)" speech

because

A dream, not a dream.

> A dream that MLK hoped to see come true.

Tailless, tail-less.

> MLK's work was terminated - cut short, curtailed - by his assassination.

Puzzled? Makes
Quite the parable.

> The speech uses a number of rhetorical devices which have their roots in religious preaching; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Have_a_Dream#The_speech_and_rhetoric

and

> MLK was of course a minister of religion. "You know, actually all that I do in civil rights I do because I consider it a part of my ministry." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Luther_King,_Jr.#Ideas.2C_influences.2C_and_political_stances

---

**Idea #2**

It's

> [Joseph's dreams from Genesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_(patriarch)#Dreams_as_motif_and_contribution_to_narrative)

because

A dream, not a dream.

> In the story, dreams become prophecy.

Tailless, tail-less.

> Joseph's [coat of many colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_and_the_Amazing_Technicolor_Dreamcoat) is typically quite a long coat - a tail-coat! But it's taken away: Joseph is tail-coat-less.

Puzzled?

> Pharoah was puzzled - needed Joseph to interpret the cow dreams.

Makes
Quite the parable.

> The story is a Judeo-Christian-Islamic-Baha'i religious text.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the new hints, here is my second attempt:

> **allegory**

*A dream, not a dream*

> Refers to the words **analogy** and **reality**. I believe "analogy" is dream-like in the sense of being hypothetical.

*Tailless, tail-less*

> The subtle difference in punctuation for "tailless" refers to two different ways of removing a "tail" from each of the words.
>  **logy** = removing "anal" (tail in the literal sense) from "analogy"
>  **real** = removing "-ity" (the suffix being the tail) from "reality"

*Puzzled? Makes quite the parable*

> Scrambling "logy + real" gives us **allegory**, which is a synonym for "parable"

Comment: You and Dr Xorile are right, but you need to combine your answers - specifically, his dream and your 'not a dream'.

Comment: Perhaps "end goal" and "reality"? "End goal - end + reality - tail" = "goal + rey" = "alegory"? (**Quite** the parable because it's missing an L)

Comment: You're brutally close. "Goal" and "reality" are the right words. What do you have to remove from "reality" to make your result anagram into "allegory"?

Comment: Oh I see what you want me to do now. It's "goal + reality - (tail-less "tail")" = "goal + reality - *tai*" = "allegory".

Comment: Oops I guess Dr Xorile beat me to it!