# Evolution's Triumph

Tags: riddle, poetry, haiku

Even though Bailey [beat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20903/to-dream-or-not-to-dream-a-haiku) me to the 17-syllabled punch, here's my haiku about one of my favorite things.

> *Size belied by name*
>   *Seen ev'rywhere but unseen*
>   *A slow moving beast*

Comment: It seems haiku don't make the best riddles since 17 syllables allow for a lot of interpretation (or I'm just bad at them). That said, I did cheat a clue into the title.

Comment: As far as I can tell, our seventeen syllables are wildly different, so I wouldn't worry too much about mine coming out first. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it a:

> [Tardigrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade)

Size belied by name

> A pretty long name for a micro-animal. It's other names are quite long as well - waterbear or moss piglet

Seen ev'rywhere but unseen

> Tardigrades can literally be found anywhere (even in space!). But they are too small to be seen.

A slow moving beast

> Tardigrade comes from Tardigrada, meaning "slow stepper"

And the title:
Evolution's Triumph

> Tardigrades can survive in really extreme environments (even space!)

Comment: Ding ding ding! Nice job figuring it out. And go tardigrades!

Comment: Tardigrades always make me ask myself "Are humans or tardigrades the more advanced species?"

Comment: You should check out the recent news on Octopi. They're literally waging battles against each other using ranged weaponry. Check out https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg22730365-000-octopuses-seen-throwing-things-may-be-using-shells-as-weapons/

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps not intended, but fits:

> Microsoft

Size belied by name

> The word "micro" belies the size of the corporation.

Seen ev'rywhere but unseen

> Windows is everywhere, but has no physical form to see since it is software

A slow moving beast

> Microsoft as a large bureaucracy can be rather slow.  For instance, they finally added virtual desktops as a built-in feature to Windows 10, while Linux has had them for like, 20 years.

Comment: Not a bad fit indeed; not the intended thing however. Don't forget the title!

Comment: Ah, but some nerds I know might claim that even the title fits if you read it as "(De)evolution's Triumph". IE: Title read as sarcastic / mocking / irony. (^_^)

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> A Bearded Dragon / Dragon Lizard?

Size belied by name

> With Dragon in the name, you'd expect it to be huge.

Seen ev'rywhere but unseen

> Reference to the camouflaging capabilities of the lizard.

A slow moving beast

> They like to stay still a lot..

Evolution's Triumph

> The camouflage was an evolutionary triumph for the species.